# How to extract values from a free-text varchar value as separate records in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, text-extraction

In SQL Server, what is the best way to extract values as records from a table with free-text varchar values?

I've got a table with a varchar column, which contains free text including some lab values. So it contains unstructured text, but luckily the lab values are recognisable by brackets, for example `[NA/bl: 137]`.

For each LabId I want to extract the lab values into a new separate table for further processing. The problem is that the number of lab values in the varchar text is varying, for some records it is 3 values, for others 5 values, sometimes no values at all.

I've created a representative data set to reproduce the problem, see the example below

```
CREATE TABLE #TestTable123(
    [_record_number] int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [LabId] Integer,
    [LabDate] datetime,
    LabDescription varchar(200)
);

insert into #TestTable123(
    LabId,
    LabDate,
    LabDescription
) values
('1001', '2022-02-13', 'questionnaire completed, labvalues [NA/bl: 141] [HCT/blo: 0.39] [HGB: 8.2] [WBC: 7.0], cardiotest completed'),
('1002', '2021-04-10', 'noshow'),
('1003', '2021-10-18', 'questionnaire completed, lab [NA/bl: 138] [HCT/blo: 0.29] [HGB: 4.7]'),
('1004', '2022-06-07', 'labresults [NA/bl: 140] [HCT/blo: 0.31] [HGB: 5.5] [WBC: 3.2], questionnaire completed'),
('1005', '2021-11-26', 'lab [NA/bl: 136] [HCT/blo: 0.38] [HGB: 6.8]')
```

I tried the following SQL but this only results in the first lab result within each varchar text. So in the example data this is only the `NA/bl` values.

```
select
    LabId,
    substring(LabDescription, charindex('[', LabDescription), charindex(']', LabDescription)-charindex('[', LabDescription) + 1)
from
    #TestTable123
where
    LabDescription like '%\[%' escape '\'
```

What I'm looking for, is the following result dataset

```
LabId  LabResult_extracted
1001   [NA/bl: 141]
1001   [HCT/blo: 0.39]
1001   [HGB: 8.2]
1001   [WBC: 7.0]
1003   [NA/bl: 138]
1003   [HCT/blo: 0.29]
1003   [HGB: 4.7]
1004   [NA/bl: 140]
1004   [HCT/blo: 0.31]
1004   [HGB: 5.5]
1004   [WBC: 3.2]
1005   [NA/bl: 140]
1005   [HCT/blo: 0.38]
1005   [HGB: 6.8]
```

What is the best way to get this result?

Comment: Ideally you should really be parsing this at the point of data entry, not *after* it's inserted into the database; is that an option?

Comment: I absolutely agree that something went very wrong during data collection, but unfortunately this is the dataset as it was provided to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the best way to get this result?

`INSERT` the data in a normalised form in the first place. Have 2 (or more tables) with a normalised design, and have a *n* to many relationship for your data. It seems like you have 3 different pieces of information in that column, and (some of) those values can also represent multiple values. Take the value `'questionnaire completed, labvalues [NA/bl: 141] [HCT/blo: 0.39] [HGB: 8.2] [WBC: 7.0], cardiotest completed'`, for example. You have the strings `questionnaire completed` and `labvalues`. Then you have multiple lab  results, and then a further `cardiotest completed` value. This should be *at least* 3 columns, and probably at least 2 extra tables.

For the values you want, you *can* do this is SQL Server, but it's not ideal. If your plan, in the future, is to be able to search for rows with specific values (like `'[HGB: 5.5]'`) then normalisation is a **must**.

For the sample data, and expected results you've given, however, this is one method, but it's not the "best" way:

```sql
SELECT TT123.LabId,
       TRIM(SS.[value]) + ']' AS Description
FROM #TestTable123 TT123
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(STUFF(TT123.LabDescription,1,NULLIF(CHARINDEX('[',TT123.LabDescription),0)-1,'')))V(Descriptions)
     CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(V.Descriptions,']') SS
WHERE TRIM(SS.[value]) LIKE '\[%' ESCAPE '\';
```

Comment: Thanks, this `CROSS APPLY` works exactly as required. And you are correct, this question was part of converting the data into normalized tables and separate columns.

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` isn't the operator that's doing the with here. It's `STRING_SLPLIT`, and `STUFF` that are, @BdR . `APPLY` works very similarly to `JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is with the use of a helper function

Now, this function strips the `[]`, but it would be a small matter to add them back if desired

**Example**

```
Select A.LabID 
      ,B.*
 From #TestTable123 A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract-JSON](LabDescription,'[',']') B
```

**Results**

[image]

**The Table-Valued Function if Interestes**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Extract-JSON] (@String nvarchar(max),@Delim1 nvarchar(100),@Delim2 nvarchar(100))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  

    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by RetSeq)
          ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)-1)
    From  (
            Select RetSeq = [Key]+1
                  ,RetVal = trim(Value)
             From  OpenJSON( N'["'+replace(string_escape(@String,'json'),@Delim1,'","')+N'"]' )

          ) C1
    Where charindex(@Delim2,RetVal)>1

)
```

**EDIT:  If you don't want the TVF**

```
Select A.LabID 
      ,B.*
 From #TestTable123 A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by RetSeq)
                      ,RetVal = left(RetVal,charindex(']',RetVal)-1)
                From  (
                        Select RetSeq = [Key]+1
                              ,RetVal = trim(Value)
                         From  OpenJSON( N'["'+replace(string_escape(LabDescription,'json'),'[','","')+N'"]' )
                      ) C1
                Where charindex(']',RetVal)>1
 ) B
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't know about the `OpenJSON` function, that's a pretty clever use of it too, I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

I'll just post this here for the sake of completion. This was the best T-SQL we could come up with. Not as elegant as the `STRING_SPLIT/STUFF` answer, but it works as well.

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp_result(
    _record_number INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    LabID INTEGER,
    LabResult_extracted VARCHAR(200)
);

-- variables
DECLARE @lab_id INTEGER
DECLARE @lab_desc VARCHAR(200)

DECLARE @idx1 INTEGER
DECLARE @idx2 INTEGER
DECLARE @lab_val VARCHAR(200)

-- cursor
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT LabId, LabDescription
FROM #TestTable123
WHERE LabDescription LIKE '%\[%' ESCAPE '\'

-- start the cursor
OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @lab_id, @lab_desc

-- iterate all records
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN 
    -- iterate lab values in varchar value
    SET @idx1 = 1
    WHILE @idx1 <> 0
    BEGIN
        SET @idx1 = CHARINDEX('[', @lab_desc)
        SET @idx2 = CHARINDEX(']', @lab_desc)
        IF @idx1 > 0 AND @idx2 > @idx1
        BEGIN
            SET @lab_val = SUBSTRING(@lab_desc, @idx1, @idx2-@idx1+1)

            INSERT INTO #tmp_result(LabID, LabResult_extracted)
            VALUES(@lab_id, @lab_val)

            SET @lab_desc = SUBSTRING(@lab_desc, @idx2+1, LEN(@lab_desc) - @idx2)
        END
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @lab_id, @lab_desc
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor

-- result in tmp table
SELECT * FROM #tmp_result
```